# How to correctly apply less in custom theme

Tags: less, magento2

I have created a theme in magento 2 which inherits from magento/blank. The theme is installed and working fine.Now i want to apply styles to my theme. Currently, my vendor_name/custom_theme/web/css folder is empty. How should I proceed?

Previously , I had created a _theme.less file in web/css folder with developer mode on and frontend_workflow changed to client side compilation in admin panel, pub/static folder removed , cache flushed but nothing was getting reflected. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:

1 :- Go to custom theme directory

```
app/design/frontend/Custom_Vendor_Name/Custom_Theme_Name/web/css/source
```

2 :- `Create _theme.less or _customtheme.less file.`

3 :- Login your SSH and go to root directory and run the below code :

```
rm -rf var/*
     rm -rf pub/static/*
     php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
     chmor -R 777 var pub
```

4 :- Refresh your website.